# How will pthread_cancel() respond when the cancellation request is queued?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

This is a basic question, but the answer seems to be eluding me. In any case, here's the background information:

According to the man pages, `pthread_cancel()`'s return values are as follows:

> On success, pthread_cancel() returns 0; on error, it returns a
>          nonzero error number.

Depending on the cancellation state of the thread to be cancelled, it may terminate immediately or the request may be queued. In my case, the cancellation will be deferred and will run through a few clean up handlers. Within my main thread, I want to validate the return value. That is, a simple approach would be to add a line such as

```
assert(pthread_cancel(tID));
```

From what I can tell, it seems like `pthread_cancel()` simply returns `0` if the request was successfully queued and not if the thread was cancelled. In other words, will the above line of code be non-blocking? My concern is that if I misinterpreted the man pages, and I have a particularly long deferment period in the child thread, my main thread will be stuck on the assertion because `pthread_cancel()` is blocking.

Comment: Warning: if NDEBUG is defined, the expression inside `assert()` *won't be evaluated* so the thread won't be cancelled! (Instead you can use `int cancel_result = pthread_cancel(tID); assert(cancel_result);`)

Comment: @immibis That is good to know. Fortunately, I have an error handler similar to what you mentioned.

Comment: It is not advisable to put expressions with side effects in `assert()`s, unless you like undebuggable programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_cancel()` will never block. It will also not tell you, whether the thread was successfully cancelled.

In mode deferred: It just sets a flag (a cancel request) which the thread in question has to actively query (potentially implicitly in system calls) and then the thread will exit *cooperatively*.

In mode asynchronous: The thread will be cancelled at any point in time (usually immediately). This is only safe in pure CPU-bound loops, not calling any system or library function, not even allocating memory directly or indirectly. Note that this is also not safe if the thread is synchronizing with other threads using mutexes or other related thread primitives, as cancelling the thread will leave all mutexes in an undefined state.

In short: Cancelling asynchronously is generally unsafe, unclean by design and should generally be avoided. There are only very few use cases where this can be used in a clean way (for example 100% CPU bound code communicating with other threads only through acquire/release semantics (lock free)).

Comment: Unless the cancelability type is asynchronous, in which case there's nothing cooperative about it.

Comment: @EOF: (cool name BTW) True, that slipped my mind. I corrected my text which was wrong before. Now there is too much text which does not answer the question. :-)

Comment: I'd probably change the "This is only useful" about asynchronous cancellation to "This is only safe". I could imagine quite a few people thinking that it could be useful - and not giving any thought to whether it's safe or not... Also, just to be complete, there's a (short!) list of async-cancel-safe Posix functions in the phtreads documentation: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html

Answer (score 0):

From my man page:

> The cancellation processing in the target thread runs asynchronously with respect to the calling thread returning from pthread_cancel().

So yes, your assert will not block.